# Typesetting handwritten "n/a" symbol

Tags: symbols, typography

I'm transcribing a circa 1890 Danish manuscript where the writer uses a symbol for "missing" values in tabular contexts. It is *not* a ditto mark, and it is *not* a zero (both of which the writer uses elsewhere), but can be thought of as *n/a*, *nil*, or *empty* — in other words **"this space intentionally left blank"**.

Since it is *superficially* similar to double commas, I have used these below, but this is obviously incorrect. I think it could be old shorthand or something. I don't know how to typeset such a symbol, or if one even exists. I have looked in the Unicode spec without success.

So, questions:

- Does this symbol exist formally, or did the writer invent it?
- If the writer invented it, how do I create one (TikZ, .eps, ...)? Should I even try to replicate an invented symbol, or would it be better to use some standard "empty" indicator (not `\empty`, but perhaps some other)? If so, which one?

[image: Example]

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\nil{,,}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{r r r r r}
    Søborg: 15 Gaarde à & 6 Td. & 4 Sk. & \nil{} Fdk. & \nil{} Alb. \\
    foruden Præstegaardens & 10 --- & 5 --- & \nil{} --- & 2 --- \\
    og Kongens Kirkejord & 3 --- & 1 --- & \nil{} --- & \nil{} --- \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Maybe `\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\nil{\reflectbox{,,}}` is closer to the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some printed examples:

These two use right-pointing guillemets: »

[image: Staggemeier]

- Stiftsprovst Damgaard, [Jordebog for Odense Kjøbstad : Indrettet Anno 1884-87](https://bibliotek.dis-danmark.dk/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=33658) (Odense, 1888), p. 57
- Otto Staggemeier, [Jordebog for Nyborg Købstad : 1ste Del](https://bibliotek.dis-danmark.dk/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=8375) (Odense, 1891), p. 19

These earlier examples use double hyphens (not equality sign!): ⹀

[image: Vordingborg]

- [Specification over det Hans Kongelige Majestæt forbeholdne Jorde-Gods, Kirker og Tiender udi Aadsherred i Sædland](https://bibliotek.dis-danmark.dk/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=13191) (1776)
- [Jordebøger over Gods i Vordingborg Amt / Jorde-Bog over Høfdingshuus Gaard og Gods paa Wordingborg Amt etc.](https://bibliotek.dis-danmark.dk/cgi-bin/koha/opac-detail.pl?biblionumber=13242) (1796)

I will use the guillemets, since those were in contemporary use when my manuscript was written.

Comment: Exist also in LaTeX the symbols `\guillemotright` or `\guillemotleft` if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

On the beautiful suggestion of the user *@Marijn* use the command `\reflectbox` to mirror the request symbol. Obviously you won't have the effect you should since your image refers to an old manuscript. May I suggest to use the `Zapfino` font package using `fontspec` pakage and compiling with `XeLaTeX` or `LuaLaTeX`.
Here there is a MWE with `Zapfino` font:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Zapfino}
\begin{document}
.............
\end{document}
```

Here there is a simple version that you can compile with `pdflatex`. You to have low quote could to use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` with the reflect symbol `\nglqq` instead of the standard low quote `\glqq`.

[image]

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \newcommand{\nglqq}{\reflectbox{\glqq}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{r r r r r}
    Søborg: 15 Gaarde à & 6 Td. & 4 Sk. & \glqq  Fdk. & \nglqq  Alb. \\
        foruden Præstegaardens & 10 --- & 5 --- & \nglqq  --- & 2 --- \\
        og Kongens Kirkejord & 3 --- & 1 --- & \glqq  --- & \glqq --- \\
        \end{tabular}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think they're actually commas or quotation marks, though. I think it may be some old shorthand (the manuscript is from ~1890).

Comment: Surely to the 100%. I agree with you because the image is an old manuscript. I have seen differents quotes but not exist of very similar. Peraphs using `Zapfino font`, probably there is a solution but it is not the same.